# Doctype with a slash will break something?

Tags: html, xml, doctype

From [W3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#legacy-tool-compatible-doctype), the `<!doctype>` should not have a slash on end (eg. `<!doctype />`), because it is not needly a void element, but it's (*quote*) "an special instruction".

But even I disrespecting the syntax documentation on rule [4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax), *could* I ignore this rule and put a slash on end or the browsers will ignore my doctype completely? *There some way to know if my doctype is working as expected?*

Additionally: XML does supports doctype too and it is need to be declared?

Comment: Why do you need a backslash?

Comment: I am building a library to generate some things, but `!doctype` run out of all common rules, and I need to know it I really should create an exception for it or I can just work with that as a void element.

Comment: I think it needs to have a html in it, like <!DOCTYPE html> , so putting a / in that seems bad. See: https://www.onlinewebcheck.com/check.php?adv=1

Comment: Which DOCTYPE are you using? If you're using ANY HTML DOCTYPE, there has not ever been a need to "close" that tag. I can't actually remember if it was needed to close it on XHTML DOCTYPE, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE ...>` is a [**document type declaration**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd); its [syntax in the W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-doctypedecl) is defined as follows:

```
doctypedecl ::= '<!DOCTYPE' S Name (S ExternalID)? S? ('[' intSubset ']' S?)? '>'
```

There is never a slash at the end of an document type declaration. It is distinctly not an *XML element*, which may have a slash when self-closing: `<tag/>`.

HTML 5 may disrespect XML rules in other areas, but as your citation shows, its legacy support for document type declaration syntax does not allow it to have an element-style self-closing slash.

You're free to invent whatever syntax you like for your own purposes, but if you deviate from standard XML and HTML 5, you will lose compatibility with tools that adhere to those standards.  Not recommended.